# list index out of range in a for loop

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, for-loop

I'm new to python and I'm trying to code a simple program, I've seen others' questions about the same error, however I'm not getting to apply any solution to my code.

```
for vh in range(len(self.parked_vehicles)):
            if self.parked_vehicles[vh] == vehicle:
                del(self.parked_vehicles[vh])
                self.places += vehicle.size
                self.parked = False
                print('Vehicle unparked!')
```

When I try to test this code above with unittest I have this output:

```
    if self.parked_vehicles[vh] == vehicle:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What can I do in this situation? I'm not getting to solve it at all. Thanks.

Comment: You are adjusting self.parked_vehicles while looping it. Make a copy first then adjust that copy so your loop stays working. You can use .copy() for this.

Comment: The cause is deleting list elements while iterating over it, which is usually a bad idea.

Comment: in addition, even without deleting element you will get same error at the end, because indexes are 0-based and you the max index is len-1. Iterating like this is not pythonic

Comment: This answers your question: [Why does del list\[0\] in a for-loop only delete half the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45683615/why-does-del-list0-in-a-for-loop-only-delete-half-the-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)